# Need to create unit testcase using jasmine marble in withLatestFrom

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine, ngrx, jasmine-marbles

I am completely new at doing unit testing using jasmine-marble.

I have a component, with the following code:

```js
getData() : void {
  this.firstObservableClass.pipe(withLatestFrom(this.secObservableClass))
    .subscribe(([firstObservResult, secObserveResult]) => {
       // expected subscription results are true and true
    });
}
```

I the spec I have:

```js
const expected = cold('(cd|)', { c: true,d: true});
expect(app.getData).toBeObservable(expected)
```

And getting an error while running ng test:

```sh
Expected $.length = 1 to equal 4.
Expected $[0].notification.kind = 'N' to equal 'C'.
```

Comment: Post your complete test

Comment: and your complete `getData` function